# Black Screen After Post on Install 12 or 13.04

Tags: 13.04, graphics, video

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 (I also tried with 12.10) on an iOne gx31 with an E8400 processor.  I run the DVD and it gets to the screen with the keyboard and little man then the screen flickers and I get nothing from there.  If it's of any help I can put in a Macpup 5.2.8 or Vista and it will boot without screen issues.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Boot into GRUB by pressing shift as the computer boots. In GRUB add `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the line that reads `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`.

This should enable your vendor specific backlight. Once booted you can edit `/etc/default/grub`. After making the changes be sure to run `update-grub` to make the changes available to grub.