# Black screen when starting from LiveUSB

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, grub2, live-usb

I am trying to get Ubuntu 12.04 onto my computer and when I boot up the LiveUSB (don't have a CD drive), I can see the GRUB boot screen but it doesn't show up the Ubuntu installation GUI.

Anyways, when I click on it, it just goes to a completely blank screen. No sound or anything. I have tried the acpi=off method and several others. None have worked. I have also tried the wubi install. Here are my specs:

Motherboard:       MSI MS-7786

RAM:    16 GB

OS (currently): Windows 8 Enterprise 64 Bit

Processor:  AMD A8-3870 (3.8 GHz)

Note: This is *not* a duplicate. I have tried every other method out there, and have researched StackExchange (yes, the whole thing) very thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
acpi_backlight=vendor
```

I answered a similar question yesterday. [Black Screen After Post on Install 12 or 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305498/black-screen-after-post-on-install-12-or-13-04/305504#305504)

Comment: Alright, I'll try that.